# Getting Warning messages from alsasrc

Tags: gstreamer, alsa, v4l2

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! videoparse width=640 height=480 framerate=30/1 ! x264enc bitrate=2048 ref=4 key-int-max=20 byte-stream=true tune=zerolatency ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,profile=main ! queue ! mux. alsasrc ! audioparse rate=44100 format=raw raw-format=s16le channels=2 ! faac perfect-timestamp=true ! aacparse ! queue ! mux. mpegtsmux name=mux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=10.0.0.239 port=9090 sync=true async=false qos=true qos-dscp=46
```

While Executing above pipeline I am receiving below warning messages continuously..

```
Additional debug info:
gstaudiobasesrc.c(863): gst_audio_base_src_create (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0:
Dropped 12789 samples. This is most likely because downstream can't keep up and is consuming samples too slowly.
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0: Can't record audio fast enough
Additional debug info:
gstaudiobasesrc.c(863): gst_audio_base_src_create (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0:
Dropped 8820 samples. This is most likely because downstream can't keep up and is consuming samples too slowly.
```

So how to overcome it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is same as warning message said *`This is most likely because downstream can't keep up and is consuming samples too slowly.`*

In other word, your process is slow and thus cannot keep up the speed of input.
Try below solutions, from highest priority:

1. Add `queue` to video branch as well
2. Set property `sync=false` to udpsink  (work in some cases, but of course not very good as it may causes weird speed at some parts)
3. Set property `provide-clock=false` to alsasrc (may work in certain cases when audio clock is bad)
4. **Tweak** the pipeline to **improve speed** in video processing branch

If you cannot tweak the pipeline, only option is .... stop printing the debug log, and accept this as limitation ...

Comment: thanks for you help, i had tried above options, but problem still there.